# C# How to extract words from a string and put them into class members

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have a problem with c# string manipulation and I'd appreciate your help.
I have a file that contains many lines. It looks like this:

```
firstWord   number(secondWord)    thirdWord(Phrase)  Date1  Date2
firstWord number(secondWord)         thirdWord(Phrase)   Date1     Time1
...
```

I need to separate these words and put them in a class properties. As you can see the problem is that the spaces between words are not the same, sometimes is one space sometimes eight spaces between them. And the second problem is that on the third place comes a phrase containing 2 to 5 words (again divided by spaces or sometimes contected with _ or -) and it needs to be considered as one string - it has to be one class member. The class should look like this:

```
class A
string a = firstWord;
int b = number;
string c = phrase;
Date d = Date1;
Time e = Time1;
```

I'd appreciate if you had any ideas how to solve this. Thank you.

Comment: What is the delimiter, really an arbitrary amount of spaces or one tab character? In the former case you have no chance to fix this mess. You can fix it by changing the way the file is generated. For example by wrapping the fields in quotes.

Comment: Why? What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? Or is this a school project or something like that? (nothing wrong with that but that limits the final solution's flexibility).

Comment: This is a job for regular expressions - you now have 2 problems! To get any sort of decent answer you're going to need to supply a few real-world examples instead of pseudo examples

Comment: @Igor That is just a beginning of a project. I have two .fob files (Navision) and I extracted the important contents out of them and it looks like this file above (.fob files have a lot of garbage). Every line in this file is a Navision object with number, name, date. I have to compare two .fob files (older and newer) based on the ID Number of an object, Date and Time. In the end I should get a .txt file with objects that are not the same (that have been changed).

Comment: Is the date/time formatting sensible? Can you give some examples - is it US formatted, ISO formatted etc

Comment: is the number of white spaces between the words arbitrary? or did you just format the posted file content not properly enough?

Comment: what happens with the first line where there is not `Time1` ? would you assign `null` ?

Comment: Suggest you edit your post with actual sample of the raw data, and also indicate what characters make up the spaces (spaces, tabs etc). Also include if the phrase field has any delimiters.

Comment: @Mong Zhu it can't happen that Time 1 doesn't exist. Date and Time are always there

Comment: @Snympi I can't give you an actual sample because there can be any character in the phrase

Comment: I think the audience will understand that the sample contains variable portions which you are trying to extract, but the real world sample will also demonstrate the rule driven formatting (delineates, separators etc.) which we can use to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following steps:

1. Use `File.ReadAllLines()` to get a `string[]`, where each element represents one line of the file.
2. For each line, use `string.Split()` and chop your line into individual words. Use both space and parentheses as your delimiters. This will give you an array of words. Call it `arr`.
3. Now create an object of your class and assign like this:

   ```
   string a = arr[0];
   int b = int.Parse(arr[1]);
   string c = string.Join(" ", arr.Skip(4).Take(arr.Length - 6));
   Date d = DateTime.Parse(arr[arr.Length - 2]);
   Date e = DateTime.Parse(arr[arr.Length - 1]);
   ```

The only tricky stuff is `string c` above. Logic here is that from element no. 4 up to the 3rd last element, all of these elements form your **phrase** part, so we use linq to extract those elements and join them together to get back your phrase. This would obviously require that the phrase itself doesn't contain any parentheses itself, but that shouldn't normally be the case I assume.

Comment: the problem is also that all spec. characters can be used in words

Comment: All characters will be included in string c - even special characters.

Answer (score 0):

You need a loop and `string`- and `TryParse`-methods:

```
var list = new List<ClassName>();
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(path).Where(l => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(l)))
{
    string[] fields = line.Trim().Split(new char[] { }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    if (fields.Length < 5) continue;

    var obj = new ClassName();
    list.Add(obj);

    obj.FirstWord = fields[0];

    int number;
    int index = fields[1].IndexOf('(');
    if (index > 0 && int.TryParse(fields[1].Remove(index), out number))
        obj.Number = number;

    int phraseStartIndex = fields[2].IndexOf('(');
    int phraseEndIndex = fields[2].LastIndexOf(')');
    if (phraseStartIndex != phraseEndIndex)
    {
        obj.Phrase = fields[2].Substring(++phraseStartIndex, phraseEndIndex - phraseStartIndex);
    }

    DateTime dt1;
    if(DateTime.TryParse(fields[3], out dt1))
        obj.Date1 = dt1;

    DateTime dt2;
    if (DateTime.TryParse(fields[3], out dt2))
        obj.Date2 = dt2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following regular expression seems to cover what I imagine you would need - at least a good start.

```
^(?<firstWord>[\w\s]*)\s+(?<secondWord>\d+)\s+(?<thirdWord>[\w\s_-]+)\s+(?<date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\s+(?<time>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})$
```

This captures 5 named groups

- `firstWord` is any alphanumeric or whitespace
- `secondWord` is any numeric entry
- `thirdWord` any alphanumeric, space underscore or hyphen
- `date` is any iso formatted date (date not validated)
- `time` any time (time not validated)

Any amount of whitespace is used as the delimiter - but you will have to `Trim()` any group captures. It makes a *hell* of a lot of assumptions about your format (dates are ISO formatted, times are hh:mm:ss).

You could use it like this:

```
Regex regex = new Regex( @"(?<firstWord>[\w\s]*)\s+(?<secondWord>\d+)\s+(?<thirdWord>[\w\s_-]+)\s+(?<date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\s+(?<time>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase );
var match = regex.Match("this is the first word        123     hello_world    2017-01-01 10:00:00");
if(match.Success){
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\r\n{1}\r\n{2}\r\n{3}\r\n{4}",match.Groups["firstWord"].Value.Trim(),match.Groups["secondWord"].Value,match.Groups["thirdWord"].Value,match.Groups["date"].Value,match.Groups["time"].Value);
}
```

http://rextester.com/LGM52187

Answer (score -1):

You have to use Regex, you may have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx) as a starting point. so for example to get the first word you may use this

```
string data = "Example 2323 Second     This is a Phrase  2017-01-01 2019-01-03";
string firstword = new Regex(@"\b[A-Za-z]+\b").Matches(data )[0]
```

Comment: @TimSchmelteran arbitrary number of whitespace isnt the problem, its knowing what the fields actually look like.

Comment: @Hasson tim Schmelter is right. I already used regex and I can separate string in words but it isn't what I'm looking for (see my post). The problem is with the third member class cause it can contain 2-5 words and all spec. characters can be used in words.

Comment: Other implementation in this thread may poof you wrong, I am 100% it can be done in a regex, even for the phrase, you have to learn regex, both of you!!